# Outputting Data on Data Extension Using Lookup and Output AmpScript Functions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I want to output some data and using 'Output' and 'Lookup' functions.

If my DE fields looks like this:

```
Name           Data Type.      Length. Primary Key. Nullable. Default Value
FIRST NAME     Text            50
LAST NAME      Text            50
EMAIL.         EmailAddress.   254.     x
```

What is the correct AmpScript to output someone's first name?

My AmpScript currently looks like this. I have a feeling my 4th argument is incorrect b/c I"m not sure what is the "Value that identifies the row to retrieve" according to [docs](https://ampscript.guide/lookup/).

```
%%[

var @firstName
set @firstName = Lookup("DE__Test", "FIRST NAME", "EMAIL", EMAIL)

Output(Concat("First Name: ", @firstName))

]%%
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Syntax is correct assuming the name of the data extensions is right.

Answer (score 2):

The fourth argument is like the field name for the first condition of a where-clause in a SQL statement.  You could write your lookup in pseudocode like this:

> Retrieve `FIRST NAME` from `DE__Test` where `EMAIL` = `EMAIL`

Also, you don't need to use a lookup if `DE__Test` is the sending data extension.

You can reference the send context column names directly or assign them to variables:

```
%%[

var @firstName
set @firstName = AttributeValue("First Name")

output(concat("<br>Hi, ", @firstName))

]%%
```

Comment: One more thing to this answer, OP should set 4th argument - `@Email` in order to make his `Lookup` function work (as long as field names are correct), it could be done the same way as shown above with the `AttributeValue` function.

Comment: Agreed, but it's not necessary if the sending DE has a column named EMAIL.